# Adding a row to the Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

In the method `addRow()` I need to add the row at the end of the 2D Arraylist. For example, if I create an object:

```
 Board<String> board = new Board<String>(1,4,0,4,"A"); //(int minRow, int maxRow, int minCol, int maxCol, T e)
 System.out.println(board);
```

the output is:

```
   |  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|
   +---+---+---+---+---+
 1 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+
 2 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+
 3 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+
 4 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+
```

But when I call `board.addRow()` (`addRow()` adds only 1 row at each call) the ouput doesn't change at all. 
For example, if I do

```
board.addRow();
board.addRow();
```

the output should look like the following:

```
       |  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|
       +---+---+---+---+---+
     1 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
       +---+---+---+---+---+
     2 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
       +---+---+---+---+---+
     3 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
       +---+---+---+---+---+
     4 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
       +---+---+---+---+---+
     5 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
       +---+---+---+---+---+
     6 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
       +---+---+---+---+---+
```

but instead it just produces my previous output:

```
   |  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|
   +---+---+---+---+---+
 1 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+
 2 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+
 3 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+
 4 |  A|  A|  A|  A|  A|
   +---+---+---+---+---+
```

Could smb please tell me what I'm doing wrong? thanks in advance!

```
public Board(int minRow, int maxRow, int minCol, int maxCol, T fillElem){
      this.minRow = minRow;
      this.maxRow = maxRow;
      this.minCol = minCol;
      this.maxCol = maxCol;

      if(fillElem == null){
          throw new RuntimeException("Cannot set elements to null");
      }
      else{
          this.element = fillElem;
      }
```

Comment: plz copy add() methods also

Comment: @RamanShrivastava, what do you mean by copy add() ??

Comment: want to see code of add() method of Board class

Comment: add() is the built in method of ArrayList @RamanShrivastava

Comment: why do u need `origRow = maxRow - minRow; myBoard.add(origRow + 1, row);`. why wudnt just `myBoard.add(row)` work? List.add() appends at the last of row anyways?
Can you post array display method as well?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava, I've updated the code in `addRow()`, but it still isnt working

Comment: can you post the method which you call to display (or print) the board?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava, toString() added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following: right now the new row you are adding has no elements, you are adding an empty row so you have nothing to print, that's why you keep seeing the same output, I reused some of your code in the creation of the board to add elements to the new row.

```
public void addRowBottom(){
        int origRow = maxRow - minRow;
        int col = maxCol - minCol;

        ArrayList<T> rowLine = new ArrayList<T>();
        myBoard.add(origRow + 1, rowLine);

        for(int j = 0; j <= col; j++){
            rowLine.add(j, this.element);
        }
    }
```

That solve your current issue, but something you need to looks is that you are not updating the **maxRow** values after adding a new row, so right now you are inserting a new row always in the same position, and this position is not the bottom (for the first time it is the bottom but for the rest it isn't since the number of **maxRow** is not been updated), the output after the fix I showed will look the same because the same values is always inserted. If you want to truly add the row to the bottom then this is what you should do:

```
public void addRowBottom(){
        int origRow = maxRow - minRow;
        int col = maxCol - minCol;

        ArrayList<T> rowLine = new ArrayList<T>();

        maxRow = maxRow + 1; //here you are updating the maxNumber of rows
        myBoard.add(origRow + 1, rowLine);

        for(int j = 0; j <= col; j++){
            rowLine.add(j, this.element);
        }
    }
```

Hope all this can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @JavierMoreno